# Where are all the skill trainers?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Where can I find a list of all the skill trainers in Skyrim?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Magic: Alteration

- Journeyman Trainer: Find Melaran in Solitude.
- Expert Trainer: Find Dravynea of Kynesgrove in Eastmarch.
- Master Trainer: Find Tolfdir of The College in Winterhold.

Magic: Conjuration

- Journeyman Trainer: Find Runil in Falkreath.
- Expert Trainer: Find Phinis Gestor of The College in Winterhold.
- Master Trainer: Find Falion in Morthal.

Magic: Destruction

- Journeyman Trainer: Find Wuunferth the Unliving in Windhelm.
- Expert Trainer: Find Sybille Stentor in Solitude.
- Master Trainer: Find Faralda of The College in Winterhold.

Magic: Enchanting

- Expert Trainer: Find Sergius Turrianus of The College in Winterhold.
- Master Trainer: Find Hamal in Markarth.

Magic: Illusion

- Expert Trainer: Find Atub in Largoshbur in The Rift.
- Master Trainer: Find Drevis Neloren of The College in Winterhold.

Magic: Restoration

- Journeyman Trainer: Find Keeper Carcette at The Hall Of The Vigilant
- Expert Colette Marence of The College in Winterhold.
- Master Trainer: Find Danica Pure-Spring in Whiterun.

Stealth: Alchemy

- Journeyman Trainer: Find Lami in Morthal.
- Expert Trainer: Find Arcadia in Whiterun.
- Master Trainer: Find Babette in The Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary.

Stealth: Light Armor

- Journeyman Trainer: Find Scouts-Many-Marshes in Whiterun.
- Expert Trainer: Find Grelka in Riften.
- Master Trainer: Find Mazir in the Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary.

Stealth: Lockpicking

- Expert Trainer: Find Majhad at Khajiit Caravans.
- Master Trainer: Find Vex of The Thieves Guild in Riften.

Stealth: Pickpocketing

- Journeyman Trainer: Find Ahkari at Khajiit Caravans.
- Expert Trainer: Find Silda the Unseen in Windhelm.
- Master Trainer: Find Vipir of The Thieves Guild in Riften.

Stealth: Sneak

- Journeyman Trainer: Find Khayla at Khajiit Caravans.
- Expert Trainer: Find Garvey in Markarth.
- Master Trainer: Find Delven Mallory of The Thieves Guild in Riften.

Stealth: Speech

- Journeyman Trainer: Find Revyn Sadri in Windhelm and Dro'marash at
  Khajiit Caravans.
- Expert Trainer: Find Ogmund the Skald in Markarth.
- Master Trainer: Find Geraud Gemaine of Bards' College in Solitude.

Combat: Archery

- Journeyman Trainer: Find Faendal in Riverwood.
- Expert Trainer: Find Aela the Huntress of The Companions in Whiterun.
- Master Trainer: Find Niruin of The Thieves Guild in Riften.

Combat: Block

- Block Expert Trainer: Find Njade Stonearm of The Companions in
  Whiterun.
- Master Trainer: Find Larak of Mor Khazgur in The Reach.

Combat: Heavy Armor

- Journeyman Trainer: Find Hermir Strongheart in Windhelm.
- Expert Trainer: Find Gharol of Dushnikh Yal in The Reach.
- Master Trainer: Find Farkas of The Companions in Whiterun.

Combat: One-Handed

- Journeyman Trainer: Find Amren in Whiterun.
- Expert Trainer: Find Athis of The Companions in Whiterun.
- Master Trainer: Find Burguk of Dushnikh Yal in The Reach.

Combat: Smithing

- Journeyman Trainer: Find Ghorza in Markarth.
- Expert Trainer: Find    Balimund in Riften.
- Master Trainer: Find Eorlund Gray-Mane in Whiterun.

Combat: Two-Handed

- Expert Trainer: Find Torbjorn Shatter-Shield in Windhelm.
- Master Trainer: Find Vilkas of The Companions in Whiterun.

[Source](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Skyrim_Trainers) Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks!  having it all in 1 convenient place is very handy.

Comment: Hamal in markarth is located in the temple of dibella, in the inner sanctum.