# Places to train in alchemy besides Whiterun?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are all the skill trainers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35752/where-are-all-the-skill-trainers)

So I thought I'd be smart and kill the woman in Skyrim who was training me in alchemy. You know, so I could get my gold back. Turns out I'd like to train in alchemy some more.

Are there any other NPCs in Skyrim that I can train from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are three alchemy trainers:

- Journeyman: [Lami](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lami) located in [Thaumaturgist's Hut](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thaumaturgist%27s_Hut) in [Morthal](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Morthal)
- Expert Trainer: [Arcadia](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Arcadia) located in [Arcadia's Cauldron](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Arcadia%27s_Cauldron) in [Whiterun](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Whiterun). (you killed this one)
- Master Trainer: [Babette](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Babette), a member of the [Dark Brotherhood](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dark_Brotherhood) can be found in the [Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dark_Brotherhood_Sanctuary) (or in [Dawnstar Sanctuary](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dawnstar_Sanctuary) after completing the [Hail Sithis](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hail_Sithis!) quest) and as a bonus, can't be killed.

Comment: Thanks, good to know there's one that's impervious to my greed.

Comment: @Alex however, keep in mind that you can't pickpocket or kill children, which includes Babette. So the only way to get back gold you've given her is to sell items.